# valid xml element in java replaceAll doesnt seem working well

Tags: java, xml

Im trying to create a xml file from a POJO , in which i have a property that stores urls,
I have been using the below method to replace all `&` in the url String to make the xml conform to standards and pass it as an html char entity but the string does not change.

```
public static String forHrefAmpersand(String aURL){
    return aURL.replaceAll("&", "&amp;");
}
```

the value might be `www.abc.com/controller?a=1&next=showResults`

I have even tried changing the above method to use "/" as i read `replaceAll` uses regular expression but `replaceAll` is not working as expected, Can anyone tell me what is the mistake im doing ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: use a library such as xstream; do not try to write XML using strings, because you're pretty much guaranteed to do it wrong

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a bug somewhere else in your code. I suggest to print the string which `forHrefAmpersand()` returns to `System.out`. It should contain the value which you expect.

PS: If you're using Java 5, you can use `String.replace()` instead.

Comment: Im using replaceAll as the string might contain more than one &, i did a System.out and it just prints the string unchanged

Comment: after googling it seems lot of people had faced the same issue
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)

This method works fine if replacement string does not contain ‘$’ or ‘/’ characters.If replacement string contains these characters, the results can be in-accurate.

Fix: Use Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement)

public String replaceAll(String regex,
        Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement))

Comment: `replace()` also replaces all occurrences but doesn't use regexp, so there are no special characters.

Comment: If System.out doesn't show what you expect, put it into the method `forHrefAmpersand()`. The code above does work. `&` is not a special character in Java regexps.